# How to extract percentage text using regex?

Tags: regex

From a text file I have to find all the line which have **containing percentages (numbers + % or percent)** for this I have created a regex but it doesnot work correctly.

regex string: `\b(\d+(%|(percent)))\b`

and my inputs are

- 423%
- 423%:
- 10percent
- 10percent:

for 1st two cases it is not matching but for 3rd and 4th it works.

My requirement is to identfy the line which having **numbers + % or percent** and around it there should be no alphabate or number

Comment: try to escape percent sign :  \%

Comment: thnx:) already tried not working

Comment: Tip: You can see if your regex works on https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word boundary after `%` prevents it from matching before non-word chars.

Use

```
\b\d+(?:%|percent\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/to2HKT/1)

The pattern matches:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:%|percent\b)`  - one of the two alternatives:

  - `%` - a percentage sign
  - `percent\b` - word `percent` followed with a word boundary.

Comment: Thank you so much. spending lot of time for correcting and finding a alternate way

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`[^a-zA-z]((\d+)((\u0025)|(percent)))[^a-zA-z0-9]`

This returns values that have either a whitespace or a punctuation both before and after the desired value.